# Home network, two routers / subnets: devices connected via ethernet cannot see wireless devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have 2 routers at home:

1. ISP router from Orange that gives me internet (I've disabled wifi on it). This is the main gateway. It has static IP of `192.168.1.1`.
2. Custom Tenda router connected to the above. It has static IP of `192.168.1.2`.

Only 4 devices are connected via ethernet to the Orange router (via switch) - all have static IP addresses:

1. Tenda router I've mentioned above (`192.168.1.2`)
2. Raspberry Pi (with Pi-Hole) (`192.168.1.30`)
3. Synology NAS (`192.168.1.4`)
4. My iMac (`192.168.1.32`)

Tenda has the following configuration:

[image]

All wireless devices at home (phones, tablets, printer) connect to wi-fi network given by Tenda. Each connected device has IP of `192.168.200.x`

[image]

**My problem in a nutshell:**

> Devices connected via ethernet cable only (like my iMac) cannot see
> wireless devices).

So for faster internet, my iMac has disabled wifi. When I turn on my wireless printer it gets IP eg. `192.168.200.123`. If I want to print something, macOS cannot find a printer. As soon as I turn the wifi on for iMac - it finds the printer and prints the document. Obviously it works because despite of being connected via cable, iMac also gets IP from `192.168.200.x` and can talk to the printer. I know that.

Same goes for accessing router dashboard. With iMac I can see Orange dashboard at `http://192.168.1.1` but I cannot access Tenda's dashboard from iMac at `http://192.168.200.1` when on ethernet. On wifi it works perfectly).

What I cannot understand is that from other way around it works - my wireless iPad can see both Orange at `http://192.168.1.1` and Tenda at `http://192.168.200.1`.

What should I change on Tenda's settings so that ethernet-only devices see wi-fi devices?

Comment: Make sure, on the Wireless routers, that wireless isolation is disabled. Default may be to enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you used WAN port on your Tenda to connect to the Orange. Your devices happen to be in different networks. Your Tenda router performs NAT from its "inside" (WiFi and LAN ports) to "outside" (a network behind the WAN port). Wired stations are same as Internet from the Tenda's point of view — so they are accessible from WiFi. And it doesn't do anything particular in the other direction, just like your home stations are not accessible from the Internet.

You need to put everybody into the same network.

---

For that:

1. Disable DHCP service on Tenda, because it is likely Orange router runs DHCP service too, and we only need one in the network
2. Use a LAN port on the Tenda to connect to the Orange. Any will do, all of them are the same. WAN ports on the Tenda stays disconnected

Essentially, you downgrade your Tenda to be just the access point, not a router. All stations in your network will get 192.168.1.x addresses and will be accessible to each other.

---

Or, else, connect anything to the Tenda LAN ports. Only one LAN port on the Orange should be occupied — the one where WAN port of Tenda is connected.

Comment: Thank you so much Nikita. Works as expected. I've learnt something new.